# when does calling the android activity's setTitle actually affects the title?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, android-activity

using eclipse to debug an android application in the emulator.
upon executing activity.setTitle() i expect the title of the emulated 
application to be changed but it does not. at what point does the new 
app title actually show?
do i have to make any other calls if i want to force it to be shown immediately at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might vary depending if your activity is an embedded activity or the top-level activity. See the documentation for [`setTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28int%29), which says:

> Change the title associated with this activity. If this is a top-level
>   activity, the title for its window will change. *If it is an embedded
>   activity, the parent can do whatever it wants with it*.

Comment: my question is related to top level activity, and yes, the title changes. the question is when does it do it? if i'm in the debugger and i have a break point after a call to setTitle i don't see the new title. but after the thread quiescences i see the new title. so is there no way to tell android to set the title NOW and see it being changed right after or do you have to wait for the thread to quiescence?

Comment: @inor: I do not know this exactly, but I would guess that the change of title won't be visible until the UI is actually re-drawn. And this is probably handled automatically by the Android system, and will occur after for instance your click-event (if that is where you change your title) has returned. If you for instance look at View.invalidate() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29 ), it says that "onDraw(Canvas) will be called _at some point in the future_", with _at some point in the future_ indicating that you cannot force it to happen _right now_.